# pCap capturing outgoing packets

Tags: c, linux, networking, network-programming, libpcap

The question is, does pCap library allow capturing packets that are generated by the local system? something like the netfitler hook `NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT` but in user-space? 
 If pCap cannot support this, is there any well-supported library that can?

Looking on the web, some people mentioned that pCap has a function called setDirection which sets which traffic we're capturing according to traffic direction but many people said this function is only on Windows; and I am kinda limited in time to learn about pCap just to test if it can do what I need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is, does pCap library allow capturing packets that are generated by the local system?

Yes.  In fact, it captures them by default.  You can, in newer versions of libpcap, *disable* that by calling `pcap_setdirection()`, but, by default, it captures both incoming and outgoing packets on the interface on which you're capturing.  `pcap_setdirection()` exists in newer versions of WinPcap, but it just returns an error; there's a flag for the WinPcap-only `pcap_open()` that lets you disable capturing outgoing packets.

Comment: Thanks, outgoing packets include packets sent from a local process to a local process?

Comment: Packets sent from a local process to a local process *over the loopback interface* can be captured on *some* operating systems (\*BSD, OS X, Linux, and, I think, Solaris 11 and later), but not on others (Windows, earlier Solaris, some other UN\*Xes).  Packets sent by non-network-stack-based channels (UNIX-domain sockets, Mach messages in OS X, local RPC in Windows NT, doors in Solaris, local ONC RPC transport in Solaris, etc.) can't be captured by pcap.

Comment: ...and to see traffic sent over the loopback interface you have to capture on the loopback interface rather than on, for example, your Ethernet or Wi-Fi interface, or, on Linux, capture on the "any" device (which captures on all interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

I've certainly use tcpdump (on linux) to capture traffic on local interface and originating from the own machine. Since tcpdump uses libpcap, this must be possible.

I'm afraid this is a rather rubbish answer, because I can't tell you exactly HOW to configure libpcap to capture your local packets. However, I would suggest that tcpdump is a good starting point - either by simply using tcpdump itself, or look at the code [which is probably quite large and complex, of course, but if you can figure out what settings you need to make tcpdump do what you want, then you can perhaps add some code to tcpdump to print the settings it uses for the same thing].

Again, slight apology for not "giving you the code".

Comment: No worries, I don't need code actually; I just want to make sure that pCap provides this functionality and that's it.

Comment: Ok, so unless you have further requirements than what I needed when I did my testing of network traffic [which was to look at the traffic my box was sending to itself or another box].

Answer (score 0):

Also [dumpcap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dumpcap) -i < capture interface> captures the live traffic,

Dumpcap is a network traffic dump tool. It lets you capture packet data from a live network and write the packets to a file. Dumpcap's native capture file format is libpcap format, which is also the format used by Wireshark, tcpdump and various other tools.

Comment: Dumpcap is part of Wireshark - and it uses pcap (libpcap/WinPcap).